# If certain element is changed modify it?

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a form and when it's submited I add a class to blank fields to highlight them to be filled.

However when the user starts to fill an input or changes a "select" I want to remove this class.

This is what I'm trying, my problem is that I don't know how to select just the element that has been modified. How can I do this?

```
$("input, select").change(function(){
    $('input').removeClass('highlight'); // Only affect modified element
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$(this)` I guess:

```
$("input, select").change(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('highlight'); // Only affect modified element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`. It's a very common jQuery idiom with all event (and many non-event) callbacks.

```
$("input, select").change(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('highlight'); // Only affect modified element
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-handlers

> The `handler` parameter takes a callback function, as shown above. Within the handler, the keyword `this` refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound. To make use of the element in jQuery, it can be passed to the normal `$()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$(this)`.  jQuery methods will use that argument as the event element by default.  If you only want to affect `input`, then:

```
$(this).filter("input").removeClass(...)
```